# Using $this->key with overloaded __get() in PHP

Tags: php

I have a dynamically loading class as a variable within another class. I have implemented it as follows:

```
public function &__get($key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->values) { return $this->values[$key]; }

    if ($key == "dr") {
        if (!$this->dr) { $this->dr = new DR(); }
        return $this->dr;
    }
}
```

When I utilize this function from outside the class it works as expected:

```
echo $p->dr->name;
```

Seamlessly creates DR and returns its name. 
When I use the same technique from inside the class the `__get()` function does not get called, and I receive NULL:

```
function drname() {
  return $this->dr->name;
}
```

I think I understand why (otherwise PHP would create infinite loop in my first example), but how do I solve this? I figured out a solution using: `$this->__get('dr')->name` but is this really the best/only way? It seems hacky.

Comment: You would be better of declaring a `protected function getDR()` function (which is called in `__get`), and internally called with `$this->getDR()->name`, but it boils down to the same, because of the reasons you mention.

Comment: @Wrikken, I actually like that -- if it's not a variable, make it a function call. No need for that level of abstraction.